# How to get number of dimensions in OneHotEncoder in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am using the [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from Scikit-learn in my project. And I need to know what would be the size of each one-hot vector when the `n_value` is set to be `auto`. I thought `n_value_` would show that but it seems I have no way other than trying out training samples. I made this toy example code to show the problem. Do you know any other solution?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = [[1], [3], [5]] # 3 different features

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit(data)

print(len(encoder.transform([data[0]]).toarray()[0])) # 3 number of dimensions in one-hot-vector
print(encoder.n_values_) # [6] == len(range(5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> encoder.active_features_
array([1, 3, 5])

>>> len(encoder.active_features_)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is to define the vector size in `n_values`. Because the automatic option creates odd behavior with missing features comparing to out of range feature numbers. Trying this example again, it produces zero vector for missing numbers:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = [[1], [3], [5]] 

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit(data)

print(encoder.transform([
            [0],
            [1],
            [2],
            [3],
            [4],
            [5]
        ]).toarray())
```

The result is as following:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

And if I try `6`it just throws errors:

```
print(encoder.transform([[6]]).toarray())
```

result:

```
ValueError: unknown categorical feature present [6] during transform.
```

As I mentioned earlier, the best practice is to define the size of vectors from the beginning:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = [[1], [3], [5]] 

encoder = OneHotEncoder(n_values=50) # maximum size for my vocabulary, fits for my memory and my future development.
encoder.fit(data)
```

Keep in mind that in this case, there won't be any `active_features_` attribute for `encoder` anymore.